# Submit form on another website using php

Tags: php, html, barcode, barcode-scanner

Is it possible to create a php script that selects elements on another website and inputs data? 
I'm trying to incorporate a Code39 Barcode generator on my website however i'm running into issues with reading the scanner.
I know this online website works perfectly http://online-barcode-generator.net/ so wanted to know if it's possible to create a script that selects values on the site i.e. Code39, *input contents* etc and the picture is downloaded locally

If it is possible, I just want a bit of an idea how I could go about starting this. Thanks!

Comment: The bottom text of there website clearly says `Thank you for using free web-based online barcode generator, based on WBB barcode generator engine. If you are a PHP developer and looking for an easy way to integrate QR-codes or barcodes into your website, please contact us.` ..

Comment: I emailed them prior to this post I should've mentioned, waiting for a response still. Thought I would try this anyway, no loss in trying imo

Comment: Sure, but you've neither mentioned that you have tried, if so then it would be helpful to see what you have tried so far and which problems you've encountered ..

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I did say "I just want a bit of an idea how I could go about starting this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but depends what exactly you want to achieve. Any automation solution can do that for you (for example Selenium). But if you want embed html form on your page and then send request to target domain (online-barcode-generator.net) you will probably hit some kind of CSRF defence mechanism.

Comment: Yes I created a form from which I'll use the posted values i.e. size + code on the website I want to generate the code. I understand you saying I may hit a defence mechanism, but if I don't try, I won't know? Any idea how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Go to target domain click submit and observe where requests goes, and what is the payload. Then on your webpage send http requests to same domain with same payload. If there is no CSRF you will get response, otherwise you will get some kind of error.

Solution 2. Install Selenium, it can open a pseudo-browser in a process, submit form, read response html that you can parse and serve to your user.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on another website to generate barcodes for you.  You can get Code39 font for [free](http://www.idautomation.com/free-barcode-products/code39-font/).  You could then generate an image using applications like ImageMagick locally.

Comment: Nice hint on the text ;) I'll give it a shot! As far as relying on another site, I don't see how that's a problem. It's a tried and tested site that delivers so why go through the effort to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

first. if its not your site you are crawling you may run in some problems depending law in most countries.

why dont you generate the barcode by your own there are many php libs for that.

if you still want to crawl a page you can use curl http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

another function could do the job aswell:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php with a strem context created with stream_context_create